# Zend Framework - getting page count inside controller or model

Tags: zend-framework

```
$paginator = Zend_Paginator::factory($select);

$paginator->setItemCountPerPage($s['perPage']);
$paginator->setPageRange(15);
$paginator->setCurrentPageNumber((int)$s['page']);

return $paginator;
```

How to get overall page count from paginator?

Because i want to set 404 header if requested page is > than overall.

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can access overall number of pages with

```
$paginator->getPages()->pageCount
```

But basically it just returns the `$select->count()` value (so piddl0r's guess was correct).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how it was generated but wouldn't counting the select do the trick?

count($select);

If the the data is coming from database Zend_Paginator_Adapter_DbSelect as an adapter for the paginator is helpful.